# Vaadin 7 - Widgetset does not contain an implementation for org.vaadin.addons.comboboxmultiselect.ComboBoxMultiselect

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Project is using Vaadin 7.

My `gwt.xml` contains :

```xml
<inherits name="org.vaadin.addons.comboboxmultiselect.WidgetSet" />
```

also `ivy.xml` contains:

```xml
<dependency org="org.vaadin.addons" name="vaadin-combobox-multiselect" rev="1.2.2" />
```

and still after recompiling the widgets I'm getting error message:

> Widgetset '...Widgetset' does not contain an implementation for org.vaadin.addons.comboboxmultiselect.ComboBoxMultiselect. Check the connector's @Connect mapping, the widgetset's GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to

I tried using older version but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Did the compilation of the widgetset work? Errors in the log?

Comment: @cfrick Compilation works, but I get this message in the application where that element was spouse to be

Comment: Then try to ramp up the logging (depends on your build tool) and see if the GWT compiler picks the inherit up etc. Do other, additional deps work properly?  Is your build tool picking up the `widgetset.gwt.xml` from another place (e.g. a target dir) and your changes where not put there? Has this ever worked?  If this is all new, are you sure, your application is using the widgetset you are compiling?

Comment: I just needed to change JAR version in project>Properties>Java Build Path to version 8 and then compilation worked